# Proof of the base case of Big Theta using induction

Tags: algorithm-analysis, proof-techniques, recurrence-relation, recursion, induction

Here is a recursive definition for the runtime of some unspecified function. a and c are positive constants.

$T(n)=a$, if $n=2$

$T(n)=2T(n/2)+cn$ if $n>2$

Use induction to prove that $T(n)=\theta(n\log(n))$

How should I do my base case? It is not a number, so how do I find my n0?

Comment: Try to spend more time on it yourself. We are not going to spell out the answer for you.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus You [already answered](http://cs.stackexchange.com/a/32128/6689) the question anyway.

Comment: @G.Bach Not this aspect, though.